# NSAttributedString Draws No Stroke with NSStrokeColorAttributeName and NSStrokeWidthAttributeName Set

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring

This example below is supposed to draw a stroke together with fill but it does not. What is wrong? I am using negative value to have stoke showed up according to Apple's documentation. If I make it a positive value, then text completely disappears.

```
UITextView *rte = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:
                                  CGRectMake(50,50,100,100)];

[self.view addSubview:rte];
NSDictionary *typingAttributes = @{
                                   NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:20.0f],
                                   NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor redColor],
                                   NSStrokeColorAttributeName : [UIColor yellowColor],
                                   NSStrokeWidthAttributeName : [NSNumber numberWithFloat:-2.0]
                                   };
NSAttributedString *str = [[NSAttributedString alloc]
                           initWithString:@"Enter text here..."
                           attributes:typingAttributes];
rte.attributedText = str;
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried your code in iOS 7.0.3 simulator and got the result:
[image]

It is not working in iOS 6. I think it is a bug.
[This approach is working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15307200/uitextview-attributedtext-with-nsstrokecolorattributename-problems?rq=1)

Sorry I don't have any explanation why in iOS 6 it doesn't work.

Comment: iOS 7 Simulator works for me too - you are right. But iOS 6 does NOT... Why?